# Disallowing to show the directories in my ROOT folder

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, server.xml

I have a **JSP web application** project StudentApp and I configured in my server.xml as follows

`<
Host name="test.com"  appBase="D:/StudentApp"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
Context path=""  reloadable="true" crossContext="true" >
    /Context>
/Host>`

When I started my application it is running fine. I have kept some folders in D:/StudentApp 
like properties,ROOT,svn and I can access all folders from my site.
For example I can access like test.com/properties etc..if I give this path correctly.
I want to **restrict only with ROOT** folder..Have anybody came across with same type of issue? How can I make this?

Comment: try putting everything under WEB-INF and see

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Since I have configured already some files,I can't change the location to WEB-INF.

Comment: You need to. Unless you want the ugly solution with configuring the access rules of your HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

As per the standard for web applciations, everything under the AppBase(except WEB-INF) is visible to the browser(if browsing directory is enabled or use types the full url of the file).
So, if you do not want users to access those files, they HAVE to go under WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Develop a filter in you web application so every request must be
   checked before processing to your application.
2. Use tomcat Valve feature and develop a Valve so can narrow the request to only ROOT folder

Unless you can find a ready-to-use Valve, I recommend the first one.